# routing in laravel with multiple htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes

I want specific htaccess file for specific route.

For example, i want to allow all ips to home route of my site but prevent access specific ips to just payment route or specific routes.

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use three solution:

1. laravel [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware)

   - code [Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/allowing-only-few-ips-to-acces-api)

here:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\IpUtils;

class RedirectInvalidIPs
{

    protected $ips = [
        '65.202.143.122',
        '148.185.163.203'
    ];

    protected $ipRanges = [
        '10.11.3.1',
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($request->getClientIps() as $ip) {
            if (! $this->isValidIp($ip) && ! $this->isValidIpRange($ip)) {
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function isValidIp($ip)
    {
        return in_array($ip, $this->ips);
    }

    protected function isValidIpRange($ip)
    {
        return IpUtils::checkIp($ip, $this->ipRanges);
    }
}
```

2. .[htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)

   - code [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377230/using-htaccess-block-access-to-a-range-of-urls-except-for-my-ip-address)

here:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /thisdirectoryandallcontents
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

[Nginx allow and deny IP](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/blocking-allowing-ip-addresses-in-nginx/)

3. [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

[How do I control IP access to my site?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-IP-access-to-my-site-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware) for access control, the `.htaccess` 'can' technically be used for this, but it is highly recommended not to.

Rough example of possible logic to filter based on ip, that can be put in the handle function of newly created middleware:

```
    if (!in_array($request->ip, ['127.0.0.1', '::1'])) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
```